# Hide internal API and methods in aar

Tags: android, security, aar

Let' say i have an requirement . i have to give my application to the client. so i created an AAR and gave it to them ,so they can integrate this library to their own application.
However, how can i make ensure so i don't want to expose all my methods and classes,api and manifest.xml files to them. Is there any way to so they are invisible to them or limited to some extent.

Also if possible they should be restricted to particular classes so they can't be able to redirect to my super classes.I don't want to expose them at all.

Comment: I am also looking to obusfact the methods of my aar file.